# Error: failure to route to my newly created app

Tags: python, django

So I'm following the django tutorial at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/
i reached the point where i should be able to navigate to the polls url instead I get a 404 error

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/polls/

Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/

The current path, polls/, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

my folder structure is

```
D:.
|   db.sqlite3
|   manage.py
|
+---mysite
|   |   settings.py
|   |   urls.py
|   |   wsgi.py
|   |   __init__.py
|   |
|   \---__pycache__
|           settings.cpython-37.pyc
|           urls.cpython-37.pyc
|           wsgi.cpython-37.pyc
|           __init__.cpython-37.pyc
|
\---polls
    |   admin.py
    |   apps.py
    |   models.py
    |   tests.py
    |   urls.py
    |   views.py
    |   __init__.py
    |
    \---migrations
            __init__.py
```

I have modified the mysite/urls.py as

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

added a urls.py file inside polls folder and filled it with

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

and finally adjusted the polls/views.py file to be

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("hello , world. you're at the polls index")
```

admin page is working fine, but I can't navigate to http://localhost:8000/polls/.
I have tried it a couple of time with different names but I did not succeed. please help.thanks

Comment: did you register your app in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Have you reloaded the application after making your changes?

Comment: how do I register my app in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: not sure what do you mean by reloading the application, I refreshed the pages, restarted the web server. etc.

Comment: I have added 'polls', to the beginning of the INSTALLED_APPS list in settings.py after your comment. didn't work

Answer (score 0):

it's working now. I think the changes I made to the files were not saved before. after I  have restarted atom and saved all the files, it's working now. thank you for your help.